# Getting a base64 string of a jpg in JQuery from an ASP (C#) Method

Tags: c#, jquery, json, string, base64

I am trying to get a base64 string of a jpg image from a C# ASP method. I have confirmed that the base64 being returned is actually converted into the image correctly. However, when trying to set it as an 's src through JQuery, I get a BAD REQUEST error in FireBug monitor.

JQuery:

```
function GetImage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Default.aspx/GetImageArray",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            document.getElementById("MainContent_output").setAttribute('src',     'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + $.fromBASE64(msg['d']));
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
}
```

C# ASP:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetImageArray()
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
}
```

Don't mind the 'GetImageArray' name, the method returns a string.

Well, SOS pretty much :)

Answer (score 0):

For those needing an answer I resolved it with the following:

C# (ASP) (Unchanged):

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetImageArray()
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(path.jpg));
}
```

JQuery:

```
function GetImage() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Default.aspx/GetImageArray",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            document.getElementById("MainContent_output").setAttribute('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + msg['d']);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
}
```

Note: Element 'output' in an asp:Image control. The only issue remaining is that the string is too large in length for Javascript Serializer, which occurs for large images. I will reply with a fix when I figure it out.